# Model group or models group?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

Let say we have a group of models (car models, for example), how would you refer to it?:

model group or models group?

and in plural:

models groups or model groups?

We wanted to create a variable for a code and were discussing about the right usage, modelGroup or modelsGroup?

Thank you!

Comment: Normally we don't use plural noun modifiers, but in this case I don't see any difference. BTW, naming compu variables is off-topic for EL&U.

Comment: You name it in whatever way will be most helpful to the programmers. Correct grammar isn't a requirement there. I tend to name them in the singular or plural according to usage. An array might be called `item` (because I index a single element, like `item[42]`) and the number of its elements in use `items`.

Comment: Personally I'd go with "model group" and "model groups". Being a group, this is implicitly a collection. You are saying what type of object is in the group (a model).

Comment: So...as you can see, there are a number of opinions here, but a definitive answer is found in the dupe. You choose.